# How to decomposing diagonal matrix whose elements are inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have the following matrix
$$
C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} u B^{\top}_{\bullet1}x & a_{21} u B^{\top}_{\bullet1}x\\
a_{21} v B^{\top}_{\bullet2}x & a_{22} v B^{\top}_{\bullet2}x 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $B$ is a matrix with two columns and number of rows equal to the element of $x$. Also, $B^{\top}_{\bullet1}$ is the transpose of the first column of $B$.

Would it be possible to decompose $C$ into $4$ different matrices as $A, B$, matrix including $u,v$(which are scalars), and $x$ **by not copying columns or rows of either of these matrices**.

My try: I can write the following

$$
C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} u B^{\top}_{\bullet1}x & a_{21} u B^{\top}_{\bullet1}x\\
a_{21} v B^{\top}_{\bullet2}x & a_{22} v B^{\top}_{\bullet2}x 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 u  & 0\\
0 & v 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B^{\top}_{\bullet1}x & 0\\
0 & B^{\top}_{\bullet2}x 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}  & a_{21} \\
a_{21}  & a_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to have $x$ using a matrix product not within another matrix. Maybe my way is not the good start.

Comment: What does $B^{\top}_{\bullet1}x$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $B^{\top}_{\bullet1}$ is the transpose of $B^{}_{\bullet1}$, which is the first column of $B$.  If that is the case, then your matrix can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11}  & a_{21}\\a_{21} & a_{22}}\pmatrix{u&0\\ 0&v} B^Tx.
$$

Comment: Your right hand side is 

$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} I  & a_{21}I\\a_{21}I & a_{22}I}\pmatrix{uB_{\bullet 1}^Tx\\ vB_{\bullet 2}^Tx}  
$$

But, how is it possible to get $2\times 2$ when the first one does not have $2$ rows?

Comment: @Saeed Are $u,v$ numbers or vectors? I assumed that $u,v$ are vectors and the $a_{ij}$ are numbers

Comment: sorry for the confusion, $u$ and $v$ are scalars. Also, I am interested in a case where no new matrix created such as $I$.

Comment: If $u,v$ are scalars, then there is no need for the Kronecker product or the new matrix $I$.